# s_sec, s_millisec = divmod(float(entry['start']), 1) KeyError: 'start' for max_word= 1

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I worked on code published on GitHub https://github.com/jrterven/audio-visual-dataset/blob/master/extract_detailed_text_watson.py the code was design to use 5 words but I want to change it to 1 word so I try do that in the code but there is an error in the run as shown below

```
found 2 files
Processing video: health_news_2.mp4
video resolution: 608  x  1080
video framerate: 29.97002997002997
entry: <class 'dict'> {'link': 'build_Dataset', 'text': 'صورة', 'conf': 0.61, 'start': 2.07, 'end': 2.55, 'bounding_box': []}
s_sec, s_millisec: 2.0 69.99999999999984
entry: <class 'dict'> {'link': 'build_Dataset', 'text': 'مجهرية', 'conf': 0.97, 'start': 2.55, 'end': 3.24, 'bounding_box': []}
s_sec, s_millisec: 2.0 549.9999999999998
/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:780: UserWarning: Note that order of the arguments: ceil_mode and return_indices will changeto match the args list in nn.MaxPool2d in a future release.
  warnings.warn("Note that order of the arguments: ceil_mode and return_indices will change"
entry: <class 'dict'> {'link': 'build_Dataset', 'text': 'مجهرية', 'conf': 0.97, 'start': 2.55, 'end': 3.24, 'bounding_box': [230, 126, 131, 171]}
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'build_Dataset/news/health_news_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:04:50.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 603 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 608x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 76:135], 468 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] profile High, level 1.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=5 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/LIP_Reading/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/health_news_2/1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 130x170 [SAR 1:1 DAR 13:17], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
frame=   21 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      18kB time=00:00:00.67 bitrate= 222.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=4.86x
video:5kB audio:11kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 13.600434%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] frame I:1     Avg QP:23.12  size:  1388
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] frame P:5     Avg QP:25.05  size:   401
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] frame B:15    Avg QP:30.82  size:    85
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] consecutive B-frames:  4.8%  0.0%  0.0% 95.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] mb I  I16..4:  3.0% 80.8% 16.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] mb P  I16..4:  1.4%  2.6%  0.4%  P16..4: 51.3% 19.2%  6.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:18.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.1%  B16..8: 31.9%  2.7%  0.5%  direct: 0.7%  skip:64.0%  L0:31.9% L1:64.7% BI: 3.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] 8x8 transform intra:76.4% inter:84.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 75.0% 89.4% 42.3% inter: 7.0% 6.6% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] i16 v,h,dc,p:  0% 40% 10% 50%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 32%  8%  5%  7%  8%  7% 10%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 26%  9%  7%  7% 10%  4% 10%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 34% 20%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] ref P L0: 68.6%  9.7% 15.4%  6.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] ref B L0: 91.5%  5.4%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] ref B L1: 89.9% 10.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f7fe8810800] kb/s:53.25
entry: <class 'dict'> {'link': 'build_Dataset', 'text': 'تظهر', 'conf': 1.0, 'start': 3.24, 'end': 3.66, 'bounding_box': []}
s_sec, s_millisec: 3.0 240.00000000000023
entry: <class 'dict'> {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_subvideos.py", line 424, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "extract_subvideos.py", line 140, in main
    s_sec, s_millisec = divmod(float(entry['start']), 1)
KeyError: 'start'
```

In this part of the code I change in it an only the number of word

```
fa = FaceAlignment()

videos_directory = args.videos_dir
results_dir = args.results_dir
vids_name = args.category
vid_proc_name = args.log_file
dataset_annotation_file = args.ann_file
if args.save_videos == 'True':
    save_videos = True
else:
    save_videos = False

# Create video window
cv2.namedWindow('Vid')

# load or create list with processed files
processed_files = []
videos_processed_exists = os.path.isfile(
    os.path.join(results_dir, vid_proc_name))
if not videos_processed_exists:
    with open(os.path.join(results_dir, vid_proc_name), "w") as fp:
        for pfiles in processed_files:
            print(pfiles, file=fp)
else:
    with open(os.path.join(results_dir, vid_proc_name)) as fp:
        processed_files = fp.read().splitlines()

# Create annotation file the first time
annotation_exists = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(
                    results_dir, dataset_annotation_file))
if not annotation_exists:

    try:
        with open(os.path.join(
            results_dir, dataset_annotation_file), 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            writer.writeheader()
    except IOError:
        print("Error creating annotaton file. I/O error")

# Get json files list names in videos directory
files_list = []
for ann_file in os.listdir(os.path.join(videos_directory, vids_name)):
    if ann_file.endswith(".json"):
        files_list.append(ann_file[0:-5])
files_list = natsorted(files_list)

num_files = len(files_list)
print('found', num_files, 'files')

# traverse all the files
stop_videos = False
for file in files_list:
    if stop_videos:
        break

    # check if current video is not in alredy processed
    if file in processed_files:
        print(file, 'has already been processed. Skipping it.')
        continue

    num_output_video = 0

    # Search for the video files in videos_directory
    video_name = file + '.mp4'
    print('Processing video:', video_name)

    if save_videos:
        # create output directory
        output_dir = os.path.join(results_dir, vids_name, file)

        if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
            os.mkdir(output_dir)

    # Load watson results
    with open(os.path.join(
        videos_directory, vids_name, file + '.json')) as f:
        stt_results = json.load(f)

    # Extract all the words with confidence >90
    words_data = extract_words_from_watson_results(stt_results, max_words=5)

    # Start the video capture
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(
        videos_directory, vids_name, video_name))

    # Extract video metadata
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print('video resolution:', width, ' x ', height)
    print('video framerate:', fps)

    frame_count = 0
    fps_processing = 30.0  # fps holder
    t = cv2.getTickCount() # initiate the tickCounter
    count = 0

    for entry in words_data:
        # Extract speech to text data
        print('entry:', type(entry), entry)
        s_sec, s_millisec = divmod(float(entry['start']), 1)
        e_sec, e_millisec = divmod(float(entry['end']), 1)
        s_min = 0
        e_min = 0
        s_millisec = s_millisec * 1000
        e_millisec = e_millisec * 1000

        print('s_sec, s_millisec:', s_sec, s_millisec)

        if s_sec >= 60:
            s_min = math.floor(s_sec / 60.0)
            s_sec = s_sec % 60
        if e_sec >= 60:
            e_min = math.floor(e_sec / 60.0)
            e_sec = e_sec % 60

        # Determine video frames involved in stt entry
        min_frame = s_min*fps*60 + (s_sec*fps)
        max_frame = e_min*fps*60 + (e_sec*fps)

        # go to min_frame
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, min_frame)

        frame_count = min_frame
        # read frames from min_frame to max_frame
        num_people = 0

        valid_video = True
        landmarks = []
        angles = []
        consecutive_frames_no_people = 0
        while frame_count < max_frame:
            if count == 0:
                t = cv2.getTickCount()

            # capture next frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if not ret:
                continue

            frame_count += 1

            # resize frame for faster processing
            if frame.shape[0] <= 0 or frame.shape[1] <= 0:
                continue

            frame_small = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=scale, fy=scale,
                                     interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

            # detect faces and landmarjs
            fa.update_features(frame_small)

            landmarks.append(fa.get_mouth_features(scale=scale))
            num_people = fa.get_num_people()
            angles.append(fa.get_yaw())

            # if it detects less than or more than 1 person
            # go to next subtitle
            if num_people != 1:
                consecutive_frames_no_people += 1

            if consecutive_frames_no_people >= max_bad_frames:
                print(consecutive_frames_no_people,
                    ' frames without 1 person. Skiping to next subtitle')
                valid_video = False
                break

            # if only one person in the scene
            if num_people == 1:
                consecutive_frames_no_people = 0

                fa.renderMouth(frame_small)

                # Put fps at which we are processing camera feed on frame
                cv2.putText(frame_small, "{0:.2f}-fps".format(fps_processing),
                            (50, height-50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,
                            1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Display the image
            cv2.imshow('Vid',frame_small)

            # Read keyboard and exit if ESC was pressed
            k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if k ==27:
                exit()
            elif k == ord('q'):
                stop_videos = True

            # increment frame counter
            count = count + 1
            # calculate fps at an interval of 100 frames
            if (count == 30):
                t = (cv2.getTickCount() - t)/cv2.getTickFrequency()
                fps_processing = 30.0/t
                count = 0

        # if this was a valid video
        if valid_video and len(landmarks) > 0:
            num_output_video += 1

            entry['mouth3d'] = landmarks
            entry['angle'] = angles

            if save_videos:
                s_hr = 0
                e_hr = 0
                if s_min >= 60:
                    s_hr = math.floor(s_min / 60)
                    s_min = s_min % 60
                if e_min >= 60:
                    e_hr = math.floor(e_min / 60)
                    e_min = e_min % 60

                # cut and crop video
                # ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss hh:mm:ss -filter:v crop=w:h:x:y -c:a copy -to hh:mm:ss output.mp4
                ss = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}.{3:03d}".format(
                    s_hr, s_min, int(s_sec), math.ceil(s_millisec))
                es = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}.{3:03d}".format(
                    e_hr, e_min, int(e_sec), math.ceil(e_millisec))
                crop = "crop={0:1d}:{1:1d}:{2:1d}:{3:1d}".format(
                    bbw, bbh, bbx1, bby1)

                out_name = os.path.join(output_dir, str(num_output_video))

                subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', #'-hide_banner', '-loglevel', 'panic',
                                '-i', os.path.join(
                                videos_directory, vids_name, video_name),
                                '-ss', ss,
                                '-filter:v', crop, '-c:a', 'copy',
                                '-to', es, out_name +'.mp4'])
                                        # save recognized speech
                text_file = open(out_name +'.txt', "w")
                text_file.write(entry['text'] + '\n')
                text_file.write(str(entry['conf']))
                text_file.close()

    # append results to annotation file
    append_annotation_file(os.path.join(
        results_dir, dataset_annotation_file), words_data)

    # save name of processed file
    processed_files.append(file)
    with open(os.path.join(results_dir, vid_proc_name), "w") as fp:
        for p_file in processed_files:
            print(p_file, file=fp)


# Release resources
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def extract_text_conf_ts(s_idx, max_words, num_words, timestamps, conf, link):
    text = ''
    avg_conf = 0
    start = timestamps[int(s_idx * max_words)][1]
    end = timestamps[int(s_idx * max_words + num_words-1)][2]

    for w_idx in range(num_words):
        text = text + ' ' + timestamps[int(s_idx*max_words + w_idx)][0]
        avg_conf += conf[int(s_idx*max_words + w_idx)][1]

    avg_conf = round(avg_conf/num_words, 2)
    if len(text.strip()) >= 4:
        out_entry = {'link': link, 'text': text.strip(), 'conf': avg_conf,
                     'start':start, 'end': end, 'mouth3d': [],
                     'angle': [] }
    else:
        out_entry = {}
    return out_entry

def extract_words_from_watson_results(stt_results, max_words=5):
    data = stt_results['results']
    link = stt_results['link']
    link = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    out_data = []
    for sentence_idx, ann in enumerate(data):
        data_ann = ann['alternatives'][0]
        text = data_ann['transcript']
        conf = data_ann['word_confidence']
        timestamps = data_ann['timestamps']
        num_words = len(timestamps)
        num_splits = num_words//max_words
        rest = num_words%max_words

        if num_words < max_words:
            maxx_words = num_words
        else:
            maxx_words = max_words

        for s_idx in range(num_splits):
            out_entry = extract_text_conf_ts(s_idx, maxx_words, maxx_words,
                                             timestamps, conf, link)
            out_data.append(out_entry)

        if rest > 0:
            out_entry = extract_text_conf_ts(num_splits, maxx_words, rest,
                                         timestamps, conf, link)
            if out_entry:
                out_data.append(out_entry)

    return out_data

def append_annotation_file(csv_file, data):
    try:
        with open(csv_file, 'a') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
            for entry in data:
                writer.writerow(entry)
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")

def remove_accents(input_str):
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nfkd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii

if __name__== "__main__":

    # Parse input arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extract subvideos')
    parser.add_argument('--dir', dest='videos_dir',
                        help='Directory with videos', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--cat', dest='category',
                        help='Video category', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--vids_log', dest='log_file',
                        help='Name of log file', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--results_dir', dest='results_dir',
                        help='Directory with results', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--ann_file', dest='ann_file',
                        help='Annotations file (csv)', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--save_videos', dest='save_videos',
                        help='Save videos', type=str, default='False')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
```

Comment: There is no `'start'` in `entry` because of the `if len(text.strip()) >= 4:` in the `extract_text_conf_ts()` function.

Comment: That's good to hear. You're welcome.